# Plot feature importance per class with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, shap

How to visualize feature importance  per class?

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(xgboost)
library(Hmisc)
library(factoextra)
library(NbClust)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)
library(fastDummies)
library(smotefamily)
library(SHAPforxgboost)
x_train_xgb<-xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(x_train),label=y_train)
x_test_xgb<-xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(x_test),label=y_test)

params_xgb<-list(booster = "dart", 
                 objective = "binary:logistic",eta=0.3,gamma=1,max_depth=5,
                 min_child_weight=2,subsample=1,colsample_bytree=1,lambda=1.25,alpha=0.75)
xgb_cv<-xgb.cv(params=params_xgb,
               data=x_train_xgb,nrounds=600,nfold=5,showsd = T, 
               early.stop.round = 35, maximize = F,metrics=c('auc'))
gb_dt <- xgb.train(params = params_xgb,
                   data = x_train_xgb,
                   nrounds = xgb_cv$best_iteration,
                   print_every_n = 2,
                   eval_metric=c('auc'),
                   watchlist=list(train=x_train_xgb,eval=x_test_xgb))

xgb_pred<-predict(gb_dt,x_test_xgb)
binary_pred_xgb<-as.numeric(xgb_pred > 0.5)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(binary_pred_xgb),as.factor(y_test))

##Xgboost featuring importance
xgb_contrib<-shap.values(gb_dt,as.matrix(x_train))
shap.
shap_value_xgb<-xgb_contrib$shap_score
shap_long_xgb<-shap.prep(shap_contrib = shap_value_xgb,
                         X_train = as.matrix(x_test),
                         var_cat=as.matrix(as.facreference_data))[![enter image description here][1]][1]

important_var<-shap.importance(shap_long_xgb,top_n=10)
important_var<-important_var%>%dplyr::select(variable,mean_abs_shap)%>%
  mutate(percentage=round(mean_abs_shap*100,2))
ggplot(important_var)+geom_bar(aes(x=variable,y=percentage),stat='identity')+
  scale_x_discrete(guide=guide_axis(angle=90))+
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(percentage,"%"),x=variable,y=percentage+1.5))+
  ggtitle('Top 10 important variable')
```

Here it is for plotting data

[image]

According to the plotting data, there isn't indicate per class (which we can't interpret each feature to binary class).

Is there any way?

Comment: The variable importance is calculated with respect to a loss function, so there is really no point in looking into this by class.